# Outlook moving my flagged messages to deleted folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I flag a message in my outlook inbox (current outlook Office 365) it is instantly moved to the deleted folder.  This has only happened in the last few weeks and does not happen with my Ipad or phone - only on outlook on my computer (OS Windows 10).  Previously flagged messages remained in my inbox and I could sort them to the top by clicking on the flag icon.  How do I change back to how it was previously?

Comment: Maybe you inadvertently set a inbox rule (a.k.a "filter") to move flagged messages to the trash?

Comment: No filters at all - I have a small workaround - by adding a follow up flag column, now when I flag an item in my inbox, it stays there and I can sort using the flag column - but I needed to add a followup flag column to make it work ...  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For people having issues of clicking the Flag icon causing the e-mail to be deleted (and when highlighted, shows "Delete This Item"), the quick solve is to expand the width of the right-most column (and in turn reduce the Preview pane).

I just upgraded to Outlook 2019 and the default is to have an "X" mark to delete the Outlook item.  When the columns are condensed and you changed your

> Advanced View Settings -> Other Settings

to turn off

> Automatic column sizing

the column location for the "X" disappears and gets condensed into the column location of the Flag icon.  If you carefully hover over the Flag, you will see that the triangle portion of the flag will show "Delete This Item" while the vertical pole portion of the flag, when highlighted, will display your Follow-Up flag setting.

Hope that helps as it was bugging me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact issue today. It was because the inbox view was set to "Unflagged Items".

Click on the View tab and select "Reset view"

Answer (score 0):

If you "Reset view" outlook will delete your conditional view settings.
This solved my problem but I had to re-configure my conditional view settings.

another solution : deleting the column and adding it back in and that seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and realized, for me, a simpler solution.
The emails are ordered by flag within the email pane instead of by date, just click the date filter at the top to reorder your emails by date instead of by flag